# How to save and read txt or json file use expo react native on phone android

Tags: react-native, expo

How to save and read txt or json file use expo react native on phone android???

How to save and read txt or json file use expo

Comment: Maybe the [Expo FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) help you